# Change of Basis Given 2 Vectors and Transition Matrix

Tags: vectors, change-of-basis, transition-matrix

> Given **v**$_1=\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 3\\
>  -4 \end{array} \right)$, **v**$_2=\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 2\\ 5 \end{array} \right)$, $S=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
>  -1 & 7\\ 2 &-5 \end{array} \right)$
>
> Find the vectors **u**$_1$, **u**$_2$ such that $S$ will be a
>   transition matrix from [**v**$_1$, **v**$_2$] -> [**u**$_1$,
>   **u**$_2$]

So transition matrices work like this: $V = U*S$

Then $V*S^{-1}=U$

Where $V=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 2\\
-4 & 5\end{array} \right)$ and $S^{-1} = \frac{1}{-9}\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
5 &-7\\
-2 & 1 \end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-5/9 &7/9\\
2/9 & -1/9 \end{array} \right)$

Then $V*S^{-1} = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-11/9 &19/9\\
30/9 & -33/9 \end{array} \right)$ Which is supposed to be $U$ but it's wrong if you check the answer by plugging it into $V=U*S$

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Are you looking for V=US or V=SU?

Comment: @gimusi Im looking for the U matrix to find the vectors u1 and u2 and it is done by using V=US and solving for U

Comment: Yes I've checked the metod is correct,there is a mistake with the inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the inverse should be
$$S^{-1} = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
5/9 &7/9\\
2/9 & 1/9 \end{array} \right)$$

Comment: god i am sad now

Comment: @mathguy It is always a good check verify directly the inverse! ;)